# How to update pocof1 mobile running on pixel experience android 10 to latest version?

Tags: rooting, updates, custom-roms, xiaomi-pocophone-f1, pixel-experience

Currently, my mobile pocof1 is running on pixel experience ROM Android version 10 but I was unable to update to the latest version as I didn’t get any OTA updates, but on the pixel experience website android 11 plus is available. And I forgot about flash and installing os as I did it by watching YouTube one year back. So please anyone can help me to update my mobile to the latest version. Please feel free to comment If want more information Thanks in Advance.[image] [image]

Comment: Have you read the install guide? https://wiki.pixelexperience.org/devices/beryllium/install/ Just like any custom ROM you can download the ROM and install it via recovery.

Comment: Please follow the official guide: [Upgrade PixelExperience on beryllium](https://wiki.pixelexperience.org/devices/beryllium/upgrade/). It says "*The updater app does not support upgrades from one version of PixelExperience to another, and will block installation to any update for a different version.*", so you have to manually flash the ROM. And please read the warnings first, since it mentions that you need to do a factory reset first (whether it will affect something later or not, we can't guarantee).